# Finding change in temperature in degree Celsius in R

Tags: r, time-series, analytics, temperature

I have average annual spatial temperature data for the last 15 years, and I am interested in finding the change in temperature in that time period. Basically, the purpose is to see whether the temperature has increased or not (`indicating global warming/climate change`) over this time, and if it has increased then by how many degrees? Then I will be able to say, for example, the temperature increased in this time period by X degrees Celsius.

How can I do this in R?

Sample data

```
year = c(2005, 2005, 2005, 2005, 2006, 2006, 2006, 2006, 2007, 2007, 2007, 2007, 2008, 2008, 2008, 2008)
Tmean = c(24, 24.5, 25.8,25, 24.8, 25, 23.5, 23.8, 24.8, 25, 25.2, 25.8, 25.3, 25.6, 25.2, 25)
```

Code

```
library(tidyverse)

df = data.frame(year, Tmean)


# Find the change/increase/decrease in temperature in the time period
# Stuck on method.....
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First of all, you can plot your data along with a regression line to see whether it looks as though the temperature is indeed increasing:

```r
ggplot(df, aes(year, Tmean)) + 
  geom_point(colour = 'deepskyblue4', size = 3) +
  geom_smooth(method = lm, linetype = 2, color = 'red4', se = FALSE) +
  theme_light() +
  theme(text = element_text(size = 16))
```

[image]

And it does seem to have increased by about 0.75 degrees between the first and last years of this data set. To quantify this, we can run a linear regression model:

```r
model <- lm(Tmean ~ year, data = df)

summary(model)
#> 
#> Call:
#> lm(formula = Tmean ~ year, data = df)
#> 
#> Residuals:
#>      Min       1Q   Median       3Q      Max 
#> -1.28000 -0.21437  0.00625  0.25625  1.24750 
#> 
#> Coefficients:
#>              Estimate Std. Error t value Pr(>|t|)
#> (Intercept) -431.5850   284.1228  -1.519    0.151
#> year           0.2275     0.1416   1.607    0.130
#> 
#> Residual standard error: 0.6333 on 14 degrees of freedom
#> Multiple R-squared:  0.1557, Adjusted R-squared:  0.09536 
#> F-statistic: 2.581 on 1 and 14 DF,  p-value: 0.1304
```

The interpretation here is that temperature increased by an average of 0.2275 degrees per year, or 3 * 0.2275, which is 0.6825 degrees. The p value of 0.130 tells us that this change was not statistically significant (i.e. it could have been due to chance)

Comment: Allan, thanks so much, one last question what is `3*0.2275` indicating, is it the change over the entire time period?

Comment: @Mandalorian yes.  0.2275 degrees per year, so after 1 year an increase of 0.2275 compared to the first year, after 2 years a 0.4550 degrees increase (2 * 0.2275) compared to the first year and and 0.6825 (3 * 0.2275) degrees increase after 3 years.

Comment: the model works on `years` and most `months` since my dataset has average monthly data for each year. So when I create a model for each month to see the respective change > `df_month_Jan_TMean = df %>%
  filter(month == 1) ` and then do `df_Jan_TMean_lmr =  lm(TMin ~ year, data = df_month_Jan_TMean)`. I get some months with a `p-value` > `0.05` and a `decrease` in `TMean` for that month over the `years`. For such months can I say that `TMean` is actually decreasing or should I run a `different` model/test fort these months.

Answer (score 1):

Is this what you are looking for?

```
year = c(2005, 2005, 2005, 2005, 2006, 2006, 2006, 2006, 2007, 2007, 2007, 2007, 2008, 2008, 2008, 2008)
Tmean = c(24, 24.5, 25.8,25, 24.8, 25, 23.5, 23.8, 24.8, 25, 25.2, 25.8, 25.3, 25.6, 25.2, 25) 

data = data.frame(year, Tmean)

data = data %>% group_by(year) %>% mutate(min = min(Tmean), max = max(Tmean)) %>% 
  mutate(diff = max - min)
data = data %>% select(-c(Tmean, min, max)) %>% unique()
print(data)
```

Comment: Thank you, so then in case of `2008`, `0.6` `diff` value will be the overall change? Or for that should I take `average` of the `diff` column?

Comment: Also how can I determine where temperature has increased or not indicating global warming/climate change?